# latex-beamer: ambiguous highlighting with \setbeamercovered{transparent}

Tags: beamer, transparency

I am having problems with the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<alert@4-> a
\pause
\item b
\pause
\item c
\pause
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to have a,b and c highlighted one after one, and in the end alert the first item.  Unfortunately on page one of the generated document b is already highlighted, although only a should be.

Here's an image of the first slide:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Using Tex Live 2010 with PDF output.  Can you post a picture of what looks wrong?

Comment: @Justin Bailey: I can confirm the undesired behaviour mentioned by the OP (the first slide shows both "a" and "b"). I'm also using TeX Live2010 and compiled with pdflatex. @TexMan: I've added to your question an image showing the problem.

Comment: OP said "Unfortunately on page one of the generated document b is already highlighted". Your image shows that "
a is hib isn't highlighted in that image - just a.

Comment: OP said "Unfortunately on page one of the generated document b is already highlighted". Your image does not show that.

Comment: Oops, I see the problem. I was looking at the bullet, not the letters. My system produces the problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-|alert@4-> a
\item<2-> b
\item<3-> c
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: read the title page of the documentation ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, just swap the alerted bullet list to display on the last slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1-3>
    \item a \pause
    \item b \pause
    \item c \pause
    \end{onlyenv}

    \begin{onlyenv}<4>
    \item<alert@4> a 
    \item b 
    \item c 
    \end{onlyenv}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \alert<4>{\item a}      
        \pause \item b
        \pause \item c
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```